# Word or phrase for success in spite of incompetence

Tags: idioms, antonyms

We might talk about someone "slipping through the cracks" if they're capable but don't find success in some area, but how does one express the converse of being highly successful in spite of incompetence?  Is there a word or idiom for this?

Comment: "Dumb luck" is the most obvious idiom.

Comment: @HotLicks I think that would often work, but I'm thinking also of cases where someone may have succeeded through manipulating a system, for instance.

Comment: The Peter Principle, explained here:  http://www.forbes.com/sites/robasghar/2014/08/14/incompetence-rains-er-reigns-what-the-peter-principle-means-today/

Comment: If they can manipulate the system, they're obviously not incompetent.

Comment: Maybe 'inept' fits? Someone who is inept lacks the skills or ability to fulfill the functions of the position they're in, or they're unable to do the task they've undertaken. That is, they've succeeded in being in a position where they're expected to do a task or tasks they're unable to do well.

Answer (score 2):

"Failing upward" I think applies to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

One expression that registers in Google Books Ngram searches is "succeeded in spite of himself," which obviously can be rephrased from *himself* to *herself*, *themselves*, *ourselves*, *myself*, or *yourself*, as the situation demands. Here is an early instance of the phrase, from a [review of *Memoirs of the Life and Scientific Researches of John Dalton, F.R.S.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=G0U9AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA382&dq=%22succeeded+in+spite+of+himself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBGoVChMInuKCyO6YxwIVDpWICh2VEgmu#v=onepage&q=%22succeeded%20in%20spite%20of%20himself%22&f=false) in *The American Journal of Pharmacy* (July 1855):

> Self-taught, [John] Dalton **succeeded in spite of himself**, for his philosophical instruments were of the rudest description, and his hands were not equal to his head ; but for original, deep thought, united to a child-like simplicity, he will not soon be forgotten.

And from a [review of Walter Richards, *Heroes of Our Day: or Recent Winners of the Victoria Cross*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4PMiAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA92&dq=%22succeeded+in+spite+of+himself%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBmoVChMI_r3n__CYxwIVRimICh2-EgY5#v=onepage&q=%22succeeded%20in%20spite%20of%20himself%22&f=false) in *The Christmas Bookseller* (December 10, 1891):

> Mr. Richards has **succeeded in spite of himself**, for the chronicle of British valour that he had to tell is but ill-related. Dates are rarely given, and the various campaigns referred to are mixed up in extraordinary confusion. However, Christmas is the time of peace and goodwill, and therefore we say no more.

In these and other cases, the person is said to succeed in spite of himself because in some sense he (or more precisely, an area of personal incompetence or weakness) got in the way and impeded his success—and yet he succeeded anyway. One way to explain such success is to attribute it to one or more strokes of dumb luck; but another is to observe that  the successful person had other positive qualities that helped overcome the bad or damaging qualities.